# Island (sketch)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

Explanation in the first image, which otherwise is just for flavor.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: (As someone who liked to draw elaborate maps of imaginary islands on graph paper in college, I wholeheartedly approve of this question's pretty presentation.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'll try a different tack, since there seems to be a pattern going on in the sketches:

In the order which I noticed them: The final one seems to have two similar parts:

> easter eggs / stir eggs

The third one as well

> half-life / half-life (or is it maybe "X-ray Ray" instead?)

and the title and the first image too:

> Island (sketch) / I-land sketch

Following the pattern, the second one is probably

> eclipse clips

the fourth looks like

> eyeshadow shadow

The pasta bowl still eludes me, but stitching together the differences between the parts (as they are pronounced), and ignoring the first one as it's claimed to be for flavour only, we get

> E-?-I-?-E

So trying to fit a plausible reason for being on an island to that pattern, the pasta sketch must then be

> Bow bowl ("Bow pasta" - "Elbow pasta" works even better, as pointed out by Deusovi in the comments)

And the radiation person probably **is** called Ray,

( **EDIT**: finally got it, that's not Ray, that's an

> Exterminator terminator!

)

which all adds up to the reason for your trip being that

> you were **EXILE**d.

Comment: The pasta, if you look to the right side, is macaroni -- AKA "elbow" pasta.

Comment: @Deusovi But instead I look on the left, and it's without doubt farfalle, AKA "butterfly" or "bow tie" pasta.

Comment: Yes... "elbow" is the *other* word you should be using for image 4.

Comment: Ah, quite likely so.

Comment: Ha! That sounds all very reasonable, if a bit boring. `;)` (To be clear: I think you have it. Interesting that my rather convoluted answer has received some upvotes after you posted yours.)

Answer (score 8):

**Partial answer**

I think that the reason for being on the island is:

> **I delivered a st——**
>
>  I haven't worked it out fully yet, but I think that each of the pictures describes part of the answer in a mixture of rebus and cryptic clue. Or, perhaps more accurate: The first step is to find a phrase by interpreting the picture as rebus and the second step is to treat that phrase as cryptic clue.
>
>  There are some rough parts in my solution. For example, part 3 is *vert*, not *vered* and maybe I'm on the wrong track here altogether. But maybe I'm not and someone can find a good fit for the fifth picture.

**1**

> A web browser with a news page: "The sun is gone". It's an eclipse on a computer. Eclipse is a popular Integrated Development Environment: **IDE**

**2**

> A half-human, half-android man measures radioactivity, which refers to half-life (or half-alive) in two ways. Interpret this cryptically and take one half of LIFE: **LI**

**3**

> A make-up set with brush and mirror. The make-up is rouge, which is French for red. The mirror indicates a reflection, but not letter-wise. Instead take the complementary colour of *rouge*: **VERT**

**4**

> A bowl of farfalle or bow-tie pasta. Perhaps this is just PASTA and we take only the contents, cryptically: **AST**

**5**

> Easter eggs (which, strangely, seem to be raw) are whisked in a bowl. Cryptically, this probably means that we need an anagram of EASTER EGGS that can be fitted to the ST from clue 4, but I haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: Could the last 2 words be 'a fgrre'? 'a fgrre' comes about by stirring letters of the word 'Rnfgre'. However, that does change the contribution of #4.

Comment: @Phylyp: Having read Bass's insightful answer, I think I was on the wrong track here. Bummer! (But kudos to anyone who can still shoehorn a sensible anser into my interpretation.)

Comment: To be fair, both answers seem equally plausible. I read yours first and it seemed you had it, then scroll down to see that answer, and go "Holy...!'